# Cannot create Facebook account: "cannot register with that email address"

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook account with a Gmail email and it's giving me the error `You cannot register for Facebook with that email address. To go back click here.`

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas? I cannot find any documentation on this error. The email address is valid, contains no special characters, and I have access to the email.

I tried an existing email that a friend uses, and this is definitely not an error around the email already used on Facebook. If that were the case, it'd give an error like:

> Sorry, it looks like xxxxxxxx@gmail.com belongs to an existing account. Would you like to claim this email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, at least in this case:

The email was registered to a memorializing account (deceased).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be connected to Facebooks support of OpenID:
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/05/18/facebook-launches-openid-support-users-can-now-login-with-a-gmail-account/

Since they support OpenID (i.e. sign in using your Google Account) they might have blocked gmail addresses for "normal" registration. Try to find the OpenID login/sign up

Comment: You can login, but it doesn't say you can register that method can you?

Comment: Try to login. The account might be created upon first login (same as on the StackExchange network)